# Program to measure small changes in reaction-time

Tags: windows-7, operating-system, real-time, real-time-systems

I need some advice on writing a program that will be used as part of a psychology experiment.  The program will track small changes in reaction time.  The experimental subject will be asked to solve a series of very simple math problems (such as "2x4=" or "3+5=").  The answer is always a single digit.  The program will determine the time between the presentation of the problem and the keystroke that answers it.  (Typical reaction times are on the order of 200-300 milliseconds.)

I'm not a professional programmer, but about twenty years ago, I took some courses in PL/I, Pascal, BASIC, and APL.  Before I invest the time in writing the program, I'd like to know whether I can get away with using a programming package that runs under Windows 7 (this would be the easiest approach for me), or whether I should be looking at a real-time operating system.  I've encountered conflicting opinions on this matter, and I was hoping to get some expert consensus.

I'm not relishing the thought of installing some sort of open-source Linux distribution that has real-time capabilities -- but if that's what it takes to get reliable data, then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

Affect seems like it could save you the programming: http://ppw.kuleuven.be/leerpsy/affect4/index2.php. Concerning accuracy on a windows machine, read [this](http://ppw.kuleuven.be/leerpsy/affect4/index2.php?url=faq.php&id=5.2).

Comment: Benjamin, thanks for the tip about the psych program.  That's interesting, and I intend to explore it further. Nevertheless, I am still hoping to get more-detailed information about the issues I raised in my original question above.